# Select string which contains punctuation

Tags: python, regex, pandas

so I'm trying to remove title from a set of professors' name.
Like `Dr.Eng, Dr.rer.nat, M.S., Dr., S.Si` so on and so forth. Basically any string that contains more than one dot.

This is an example list after I have split the name and the title based on ","

```
2      [CHOTIMAH,  Dr.,  M.S., RINTO ANUGRAHA NQZ,  S...
3      [HARSOJO,  S.U.,  M.Sc.,  Dr., SUDARMAJI,  S.S...
4      [IKHSAN SETIAWAN,  S.Si.,  M.Si., ARI SETIAWAN...
5      [EKO SULISTYA,  Dr.,  M.Si., YOSEF ROBERTUS UT...
6       [SUNARTA,  Drs.,  M.S., WAGINI R.,  Drs.,  M.S.]
7      [BAMBANG MURDAKA EKA JATI,  Drs.,  M.S., KAMSU...
8      [AHMAD KUSUMA ATMAJA,  S.Si.,  M.Sc.,  Dr.Eng....
9                    [MOH. ALI JOKO WASONO,  M.S.,  Dr.]
```

I have tried `r'\S*[^\w\s]\S'` but it returned

```
CHOTIMAH,  INTO ANUGRAHA NQZ,   .
HARSOJO,   UDARMAJI,  i.
IKHSAN SETIAWAN,  RI SETIAWAN,   ng.
EKO SULISTYA,  OSEF ROBERTUS UTOMO,  Dr.
SUNARTA,  AGINI   .
BAMBANG MURDAKA EKA JATI,  AMSUL ABRAHA,   Prof.
AHMAD KUSUMA ATMAJA,   ITRAYANA,   Dr.
MOH. ALI JOKO WASONO,  Dr.
```

Some professors' names are shortened to XXX. Ex: `MOHAMMAD TO MOH.` And I don't want that to get removed.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: if it is list, try apply(pd.Serise)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\w{0,}\.(\w{0,}\.)?` This regex test string will grab any length word followed by a period, and will look for another word of any length followed by a period optionally. This captures `Dr.`, `M.S.` etc. I'm pretty sure that's what you're asking for, if not let me know.

In the future you can use regexr.com to easily test regex matches. Also you've tagged this post with `Python` and `Pandas` but those aren't really relevant tags. Please either include more code to make tags relevant or avoid using irrelevant tags

Comment: Whoa, thanks! I tagged python because I want to use it on my python code (specifically, my pandas dataframe) and I'm pretty new here ehe. Thanks for the suggestion nonetheless.

Comment: Btw, titles like "Dr.Biotech", "Dr", "MBA", and "S.Si" didn't get removed. Do you think using simple regex will solve this?

Comment: Your best bet is probably to match those strings explicitly since they are so specific

Comment: for python you can do `if variable in list` and have  a list like `['Dr', 'Dr.', 'MBA']` etc

Comment: Those are actually just an example because apparently academic titles are so...varied